# why there is an error of undefined reference on raylib?

Tags: c, raylib

I have tried serval times, but it won't work.

The code that I used is

```
gcc main.c -o main.exe -O1 -Wall -std=c99 -Wno-missing-braces -I E:\Dev\w64devkit\i686-w64-mingw32\include -L E:\Dev\w64devkit\i686-w64-mingw32\lib -lraylib
```

and the error was

```
E:\Dev\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\jake\AppData\Local\Temp\cc8QGLal.o:test.c:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `InitWindow'
E:\Dev\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\jake\AppData\Local\Temp\cc8QGLal.o:test.c:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `SetTargetFPS'
E:\Dev\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\jake\AppData\Local\Temp\cc8QGLal.o:test.c:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `WindowShouldClose'
E:\Dev\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\jake\AppData\Local\Temp\cc8QGLal.o:test.c:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `IsMouseButtonDown'
E:\Dev\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\jake\AppData\Local\Temp\cc8QGLal.o:test.c:(.text+0x50): undefined reference to `GetMouseDelta'
E:\Dev\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\jake\AppData\Local\Temp\cc8QGLal.o:test.c:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to `CloseWindow'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status'
```

how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Just a little nitpicking: The "code" that you use isn't the code, it's the *command* you use to build the code. With that said, it "should"™ work, since you link with the right library (unless you have more libraries named `raylib` in other locations). Are those the *only* messages you get? Please copy-paste the complete and full text from the console-window or build-log window into your question.

Comment: How and where did you install raylib?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that the library exists because this is a link error.

According to the [manual](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/wiki/Working-on-Windows), it should usually be under `C:\raylib`.

Comment: Thanks for your information.  Now I know what the raylib is.
https://www.raylib.com/cheatsheet/cheatsheet.html
However, this is a linking error and need to assign the correct library to link.

Comment: I customized the installation to my portable drive